# How to bind using pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

This is the structure of my program:

[image]

I'm trying to bind my program in C++ with a GUI in python. I'm using pybind11 and I have a python_binding.cpp file for the bind and some ".h" and ".cpp" with the methods in other directories. I include the ".h" files but somehow the python_binding.cpp it's not able to recognize them.

The file config.cpp only has one void method, "cargar_configuracion()" and this is how it looks like in the binding:

```
#include "Ejemplo/config.h"

PYBIND11_MODULE(Example, m) {
m.doc() = "Binding"; // optional module docstring


m.def("cargar_configuracion", &cargar_configuracion);
```

The result of this is the following error:

```
undefined reference to `cargar_configuracion()'
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I have my .cpp and .h with the binding.cpp in the same directory?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to bind a certain key to a function? in that case you could use 

    
`def callback(event):
    print('X: %d, Y: %d' %(event.x,event.y) )`
 and then you need to bind left click to that function by doing this:
`bind("<Button-1>", callback) `

Comment: I don't understand what do you ask, I just need to run the method "cargar_configuracion()" in python.

Comment: What *key*/button would you want to be pressed for it to run cargar_confiuracion()?

Comment: I have one button on my GUI to do that

Comment: Then you need to inform us on what module youre using to display your GUI button

Comment: I only have one module for pybind, I'm wrapping all of my program in one dll and then I import that dll in python and use it as a library

Comment: You specified that you had a GUI button, are you using tkinter to create that button? for instance `button1 = Button(text='do command')`

Comment: I'm using pyqt: 
bViewResult = QtWidgets.QPushButton('View Results', self)
bViewResult.clicked.connect(self.openCSV)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pybind11 looks fine, this is a linker error. It looks like `config.cpp` is in another project within your solution, and is being built within a separate executable. You have two options here, either copy config.cpp into the same directory or reconfigure `Ejemplo` to be a static library and specify it as a dependency in the properties of the python wrapper project.

Answer (score 0):

> Change your code from:

```
bViewResult = QtWidgets.QPushButton('View Results', self) 
bViewResult.clicked.connect(self.openCSV)
```

> to:

```
bViewResult = QtWidgets.QPushButton('View Results', self)
bViewResult.clicked.connect(cargar_configuracion())
```

Comment: Sorry but that's not what I'm asking for, maybe I wasn't too clear in my question. I want to know how to make the declaration for a C++ method using Pybind11 because the way I did it makes an error.